# Perl strict decode_base64

Tags: perl, base64

How can i get functionality in MIME::Base64::decode() as in php [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) function with **strict** parameter?

Comment: And what is your code ?

Comment: The [CPAN page](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/MIME-Base64-3.13/Base64.pm) has examples, which do just this.

Comment: My input can contain corrupted and mismatched data that base64 alphabet can not have, i need that the function return boolean false if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $c = '[A-Za-z0-9+/]';
my $strict = qr/
   ^
   (?:$c{4})*+
   (?:$c(?:==|$c(?:=|$c))=)?+
   \z
/x;

sub php_base64_decode {
   return undef if $_[1] && $_[0] !~ $strict;
   return decode_base64($_[0]);
}
```

Not sure what PHP's `base64_decode` does exactly, so you might have to tweak the pattern in `$strict`.

Comment: Well it seems that this is the only method, but i must add all utf8 characters to pattern :(

Comment: @Aphex, That makes no sense.